# Soap request with python (suds)

Tags: python, web-services, soap, suds

I would like to make a soap request with python. I'm trying the suds library.
I have a xml file to make the request, here's my code:

```
from suds.client import Client
import requests

with open("FILE_PATH","r") as f:
    file=f.read()

url='url'
client = Client(url)

httpHeaders = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml', 'SOAPAction': 'ACTION'}
client.set_options(headers=httpHeaders)
print client.service.test(__inject={'msg': file})
```

Actually i get this error:

> Exception: No services defined

The message is obvious, but i haven't understood haw to solve it. Any seggestion ? ... may be someone know a batter way to do this.

Comment: i assume you are actually using a correct url for a WSDL file and not actually the string `url`

Comment: also exact duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103950/webservice-request-with-python-suds-by-xml